# Prevent a listener from being activated depending on where it was called in Symfony

Tags: php, listener, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony project with a lot of bundles.

In one of them, I have a standard Doctrine listener like this:

```
class MyListener
{

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof MyEntity) {
            //do something
        }
...
```

Now I've created a new Bundle that also loads these Entities in a Controller.

As expected, it also triggers the postLoad in the listener.

I need it not to trigger it, or if it's triggered by this Bundle/Controller, to don't do anything, something like:

```
class MyListener
{

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($caller = "DontTriggerBundle")
            return true;
        }

        if ($entity instanceof MyEntity) {
            //do something
        }
...
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: just remove `doctrine.event_listener` from services?

Comment: @Noman That'll disable the listener for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved it:

Added the request stack to the service:

```xml
<service id="myservice>
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
</service>
```

Then got the controller like this:

```php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/AcmeListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class AcmeListener
{
    /** @var Request */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * AcmeListener constructor.
     *
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $controller = $this->request->attributes->get('_controller');

        if (strpos($controller, 'DontTriggerController::indexAction') !== false) {
            // Do nothing
            return;
        }
        // Do somethings
    }
}
```

hope this helps someone